# Evaluate $\int\frac{dz}{\sqrt{\left(z-a\right)\left(z-b\right)\left(z-c\right)}}$

Tags: integration, special-functions

What is the method to do this integration?

$$\int\frac{dz}{\sqrt{\left(z-a\right)\left(z-b\right)\left(z-c\right)}}$$

When I checked it in Mathematica it gave the result in terms of  EllipticF.

The result what I got in Mathematica is
$\frac{-2}{\sqrt{b-a)}}F[sin^{-1}(\frac{\sqrt{b-a}}{\sqrt{z-a}}),\frac{a-c}{a-b}]$

Comment: Such integrals don't have elementary closed forms; they require special functions called "elliptic functions. This paper (http://www.mhtlab.uwaterloo.ca/courses/me755/web_chap3.pdf) has a summary.

Comment: Posting your Mathematica result would be helpful.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt I added the mathematica result.

Comment: There is no better way than what Mathematica said.

Comment: @YvesDaoust  I don't want the alternative answer, I want to know the method.

Comment: @m.bubu: do you know about the elliptic integrals ?

Comment: @connor, they're elliptic integrals and not elliptic functions. One is the inverse of another.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you consider an answer. If you look at [DLMF section 19.16.1](http://dlmf.nist.gov/19.16#E1) This is called a symmetric elliptic integral denoted by $2R_f(-a,-b,-c)$. Another possible answer is what Mathematica gives you. There are several tables of integrals such as [Gradshteyn and Ryzhik](http://www.mathtable.com/gr/) and you can find answers in them. There is no **one** method. There are a variety of possible methods and answers for you to choose from and you can use whatever is more familiar or convenient for you.

For this particular integral, it is clearly symmetric in $a,b,c$ but Mathematica used one particcular ordering. There are five others to choose from.

Comment: @m-bubu: You can use the formulas from http://dlmf.nist.gov/19.25.iii
to convert $R_F$ to Legendre style functions.

Comment: @gammatester Yes, of course, but the advantage of $R_f$ is that it is symmetric. The advtange of $F$ is that its study and tables goes back to Legendre 200 years ago.

Comment: I know. My comment was not a critique of your answer, but a hint to m-bubu to arrive at the Mathematica result. Moreover the Carlson form has the advantage of an unambiguous notation compared with the others using modulus $k$ (DLMF) or parameter $m$ (Mathematica).